# django slug without defining this in model

Tags: django, django-views, slug

I have database with records, and I like to use "title" record as link to the article, but problem is that on model slug is not defined. I not entirely sure if i can use urls.py and views.py only to generate url path to the article.
So far here is my code.

```
class ArticleView(ListView):
    template_name = 'article.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        article = self.kwargs.get('feed_title', None)
        return article

    def get_context_data(self, request, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleView, self).get(request, **kwargs)
        return context
```

and my url:

```
url(r'^(?P<article>[-\w]+)/$', ArticleView.as_view(), name='article')
```

Comment: Why not just add a slugfield to the model?

Comment: As far as I understand "slug-url" is created while article is added and is stored in database. Adding now slug into model it will be creating slag-url for new article, but what about already existed articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue, I added slugfield to My model as was suggested by @Gary, then I run South migration:

```
python manage.py schemamigration Myapp --auto
python manage.py migrate Myapp
```

Then for create the slug field entries for all my existing data. I have used Django shell:

```
python manage.py shell
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from MyApp.models import MyModel
```

First just for test:

```
>>> for obj in MyModel.objects.all():
...     obj.slug = slugify(obj.title)
...     print(obj.slug)
```

Then generate slug and save:

```
>>> for obj in MyModel.objects.all():
...     obj.slug = slugify(obj.title)
...     obj.save()
... 
>>>
```

With this I created slug-url for more than 3000 entries. Now I will focus how to create a template and serve each entry with url as title for article.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a slugfield to your model and specify a default value calculated from your name field. If you're using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) for your migrations (and if you're not you should be!) then it will use the default value when migrating existing instances. Django's [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) feature may also be useful for adding slugs to existing articles.

Comment: Thank you @Garry for your replay, yes I using South and I agree with you that Django's slugify feature may be useful.